How to add additional databases after mysql initialization in docker container?
We are using docker and have a mysql container. We use docker-entrypoint-initdb.d to initialize our mysql container with multiple databases and associated schema. This has been working great for a long time.
We now need to add an additional database to that same container for all team members (large team), but we don't want to blow away any existing database data. We can't get the initialization scripts to run again. We've added another sql file that contains the create database command, but it won't run again, since the initialization has already been done for everyone.
I recognize this could be done manually, but we have multiple instances of the mysql container per individual, and many individuals. The manual process is not going to work for us.
Is there a way to get this to run for new scripts (.sql or .sh) that are added to that directory, or is there some other standard way of doing what I'm asking?
We have added a new .sql file to the directory, but it is not processed, since the initialization has already happened.

Usually, in a container setup, a database container only contains one database which is initialized using initdb.d scripts. Subsequent changes are then done using migrations from the application. You might consider creating a new container for the new database.

what we do in our initdb script is: Create Database A; Create Table A; Create Table B; Create Database D; Create Table E; Create Table F. If we want to add a table G in database A we add between Create Table B and Create Database D

@HansKilian - that is how we are setup. In mysql you can have a single instance/host with multiple databases. We simply want to add an additional database to an existing db host in the container. We are setup to do migrations against specific databases, but we need the new database to exist before we can run migrations. I'm trying to figure out how to get that new database created on many local environments. It's easy if you start out fresh, but apparently there's not a good way to do it for existing db containers.

It sounds to me like you are doing X databases in 1 container. What I'm saying is you can create a second database container, so you'll have X+1 databases and 2 containers. One container with all your existing databases and one with your new database. In a microservices setup, databases are usually kept in their own containers, so you'd have X databases and X containers, each database in their own container.
